# start with a fresh HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

the following code clears the canvas on a button click

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clears
```

but, When I try to redraw on it, The old drawing appears which I don't want it to. I want to start painting on a fresh blank canvas

http://jsfiddle.net/umwc5/

How do I achieve that?

in case you wish to see the entire code..

```
  $(function () {
  var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = c.getContext("2d");
  var clickX = new Array();
  var clickY = new Array();
  var clickDrag = new Array();
  var paint;

  $('#canvas').mousedown(function (e) {
      var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
      var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

      paint = true;
      addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
      redraw();
  });


  $('#canvas').mousemove(function (e) {
      if (paint) {
          addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
          redraw();
      }
  });

  $('#canvas').mouseup(function (e) {
      paint = false;
  });

  $('#canvas').mouseleave(function (e) {
      paint = false;
  });

  $('#clear').click(function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clears

  });

  function addClick(x, y, dragging) {
      clickX.push(x);
      clickY.push(y);
      clickDrag.push(dragging);
  }

  function redraw() {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clears the canvas

      context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
      context.lineJoin = "round";
      context.lineWidth = 2;

      for (var i = 0; i < clickX.length; i++) {
          context.beginPath();
          if (clickDrag[i] && i) {
              context.moveTo(clickX[i - 1], clickY[i - 1]);
          } else {
              context.moveTo(clickX[i] - 1, clickY[i]);
          }
          context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
          context.closePath();
          context.stroke();
      }
  }

  });
```

Comment: Could you please click edit and copy/paste the code from the fiddle into the SO question? SO is like a library, and needs the code for future visitors, and the fiddle may go dead after a while.

Comment: @Paul Done! Added the entire code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to clear the following arrays `clickX`, `clickY` and `clickDrag`:

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
clickX = []; // clear mouse "logs"
clickY = [];
clickDrag = [];
```

**[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umwc5/2/)**

When you click or drag the mouse the `addClick` method is called, which populates the arrays `clickX`, `clickY` and `clickDrag` with the mouse coordinates. When the `redraw` method is called it plots the points again on the canvas. So clearing these arrays will solve your problem.

Comment: I have one other doubt, suppose a webpage with the above created canvas is open and active and The PC is connected to a signature pad, If I sign on that signature pad will the signature be drawn on that canvas?

Comment: @rps I actually never owned one of these so I'm not sure what is the interface with it.. this is a legit thought.. has to be tested

Comment: what if it is a pen tablet like [this](http://www.amazon.com/WACOM-MTE450-Small-Tablet-Only/dp/B002MI02BK) will it work??

Comment: @rps as stated earlier. I don't own a wacom so I have no definite answer.

Comment: @rps yes it will, when the tablet is connected (via usb) it acts as a mouse device and will start broadcast "mouse" events. This is determined by the hardware/OS not the browser/canvas etc.